# unable to select/unselect checkbox inside label tag

Tags: html, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to run this script in using java selenium, I am getting **ERROR**: *"unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (1142, 356)"*
please see the below code:

```
wd.get("https://login.yahoo.com/?.src=ym&.intl=us&.lang=en-
US&.done=https%3a//mail.yahoo.com");
WebElement e = wd.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@type='text']"));  
e.sendKeys("abcd");
wd.findElement(By.xpath(".//*@id='yui_3_18_1_11_1474955984806_126']'))]")).c lick();
```

Actual HTML Tag in the webpage:

```
<input id="persistent" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" checked="" tabindex="3" value="y" name=".persistent">
<label for="persistent" id="yui_3_18_1_11_1474987692298_128">Stay signed in</label>
```

Can anyone help me how to select/unselect the checkbox when is attached to the label tag.

Comment: Have you tried getting the checkbox by `@id='persistent'` ?

Comment: Yes, but i ended with same result

Answer (score 0):

The xpath you mentioned is invalid. Try the below xpath

```
wd.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='yui_3_18_1_11_1474955984806_126']")).click();
```

you haven't mentioned `[` before `@id`

Comment: Thanks, But now it is showing as "no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='yui_3_18_1_11_1474987692298_128']"}      ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' -------------------------- Have you tried it .. is it working for you...... ?

Comment: i guess the id is randomly generated, can you try using css selector as below,`wd.findElement(By.cssSelector("label[for='persistent']")).click();`

Comment: Still same "no such element: Unable to locate element.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you're trying to click on `<label>` element instead of `<input id="persistent" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" checked="" tabindex="3" value="y" name=".persistent">`
 element. You should try to locate `checkbox` element instead using `By.id()` as below :-

```
wd.findElement(By.id("persistent")).click();
```

Or if you want to click on `<label>` element, try using `By.cssSelector()` as below :-

```
wd.findElement(By.cssSelector("label[for = 'persistent']")).click();
```

Comment: No that will also not work.  I found the answer i am posting it please check it and share if it is useful

Comment: What do you mean not work?? Is there any exception?? Need to share as well

Comment: Please see below I have posted. Please update me if i am wrong

Comment: Your provided solution looks you want to click on label element while your question about click on checkbox element

Comment: I am sorry if it is confusing. As I am new and still in learning face.

Comment: @ABAJAVa no problem, but If you want to click on `label` element best way to use cssSelector insteadof xpath as suggested answer because using cssSelector to locate an element is much faster than xpath. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally it is working with below xpath

```
wd.findElement(By.xpath(".//label[@for='persistent']")).click();
```

Here we should target the label tag along with its attribute. So that the webelement is easily accessible.

Answer (score 0):

```
WebDriver wd = null;
        wd = new FirefoxDriver();
        //Open website page
        wd.get("https://login.yahoo.com/?.src=ym&.intl=us&.lang=en-US&.done=https%3a//mail.yahoo.com");
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        WebElement e = wd.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@type='text']"));  
        e.sendKeys("abcd");
        wd.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='persistency']/div/label")).click();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        wd.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='persistency']/div/label")).click();
```

This code will work. Beacuse I have tried and it runs successful.

Comment: @ABAJAVa, You can's use label's id ui_3_18_1_11_1474955984806_126 because it generates dynamically after once clicking on checkbox.